# How can I get this SQL query to work...?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I am making a game for class and I decided to make a leaderboards page. As I have an admin area too I need to grab data from both tables in the page.

The two tables are `user_settings` and `leaderboards`.
This is the code on my leaderboards.php page:

```
    <?php $records = array();

    if ($results = $db->query("SELECT * FROM user_settings UNION SELECT * FROM leaderboards")) {
        if ($results->num_rows) {
    while ($row = $results->fetch_object()) {
        $records[] = $row;
    }
    $results->free();
        }
    }

      ?>
    <?php foreach ($records as $data) { ?>

...the HTML etc...

<?php } ?>
```

What do I need to change in order to make this query work. Do I need to change the foreach loop? or...? I have only so far needed to grad data from one table so I'm not sure how to get this to work.

EDIT:

The `user_settings` table is for admin set config such as the site name etc. So far all I am doing is trying to do is select all from two tables without the page breaking, at the moment it is breaking. I have a feeling it is to do with the foreach loop and some of the code underneath the query. At the moment I do not want to grab any data from the database, I just want to select all successfully so the page doesn't break.

Comment: Please add example data and expected output.

Comment: I highly doubt user_settings and leaderboards have identical structures. Union queries must have identical data types for each result position. You should post the structure of the 2 tables. Here's the docs on union: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

Comment: Since you do want to access them as objects, you should just use `while ($data = $results->fetch_object()) { ... HTML ... }`

Comment: Perhaps a JOIN will work instead of the UNION.  Otherwise, just make two separate queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Kai Qing stated you are using `UNION`. As I don't know what your table structures are I cannot guarantee this is what you are after however I believe you are wanting to select all from two tables that do not share the same structure therefore you will want to do:

```
if ($results = $db->query("SELECT * FROM user_settings, leaderboards")) {
```

I hope this helps.